# MySQL JSON query on a subquery

Tags: mysql, json, wildcard, contains

I have a Table A

```
    id 
    something
    jsonModel
```

jsonModel could look like this

```
{  
   "text":"foo",
   "subkey1":{  
      "entity":{  
         "name":"foo",
         "customId":"59d61ffcf5bcb11f250d73275a252b62624eac000180ab59"
      }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to select a row from table A when a certain ID is contained in the the jsonModel.

I have tried this but it does not work saying I'm not allowed to use wildcards in the expression

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM A 
WHERE json_contains(jsonModel,'59d61ffcf5bcb11f250d73275a252b62624eac000180ab59', $**.customId)
```

Is there a way to achieve this knowing that I do not know where in the model customId can be?

EDIT:

I ended up writing this which works but I don't know which solution between this or wchiquito is best

```
SELECT * 
from A WHERE 
JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(jsonModel, '$**.customId'),  '"59d61ffcf5bcb11f250d73275a252b62624eac000180ab59"');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  `id`,
  `jsonModel`
FROM
  `A`
WHERE
  JSON_SEARCH(
    `jsonModel`,
    'one',
    '59d61ffcf5bcb11f250d73275a252b62624eac000180ab59',
    NULL,
    '$**.customId'
  ) IS NOT NULL;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pG4eA1atzpef6AuErDBdd4/0).

Comment: Before you wrote your solution I kept playing around and ended up with
"SELECT * from A WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(jsonModel, '$**.customId'), '"59d61ffcf5bcb11f250d73275a252b62624eac000180ab59"');

Is there any performance issue with this ?

Comment: @Johny19: A sentence like the following also works: `SELECT \`jsonModel\` -> '$**.customId' = JSON_ARRAY('59d61ffcf5bcb11f250d73275a252b62624eac000180ab59')`. Try to perform tests to determine the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Even tough its not correct or best approach but it works,

```
SELECT * from `A` where `jsonModel` like '%customId%59d61ffcf5bcb11f250d73275a252b62624eac000180ab59%'
```